# Environment set with DotEnv not working in react

Tags: reactjs, dotenv

I want to use environment variables in react. I found it in this documentation: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env

But when I try to get the variables defined in my .env-File, I get always only the default vars:

```
{
  "NODE_ENV": "development",
  "PUBLIC_URL": ""
}
```

How can I use the feature?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#customizing-environment-variables-for-arbitrary-build-environments

It's required to install a additional npm package called env-cmd (see https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd).